# Anybody that knows hot to use TOPCASED?

Tags: c, eclipse-plugin, uml, topcased

I'm starting to use TOPCASED and I was wondering if C code could be generated from a state machine diagram. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, this feature isn't specific to topcased. Topcased UML models conform to the Eclipse UML2 Metamodel, which most generator frameworks, like openArchitectureWare (Xpand) support. Of course, you have to implement the state machine to C mappings by yourself.